# bash echo color to textfile

Tags: bash, colors, echo

How can I write colored text using bash?

```
RED='\033[0;31m'
GREEN='\033[0;32m'
NC='\033[0m' 
greprc=$?
if [[ $greprc -eq 0 ]] ; then
 echo -e "${GREEN} converged${NC}" >>log
else
  echo -e "${RED} not converged${NC}" >>log
fi
```

This, if prompted to terminal only, colorize the text. But, when I write this to a file, true to plain text, it does not colorize the text in `log` file. How I can write colored text in the log?

Comment: `greprc`  requrns some grep value, 0, if  grep is successful, 1 if not, as per grep manual. But for my question, I think, that is not essential, and may be you can initialize as 0/1.

Comment: Doesn't `cat log` trigger colors? If `echo` does, so should `cat` with the same output. Or do you mean "colorize the text in `log` file" *in some editor*?

Comment: [`less -R log`](https://superuser.com/a/117842/432690) should work.

Answer (score 1):

This is the copy-pasted output of `cat` of a colorized file:

```
[36m 
hello36
[35m 
hello35
[37m 
hello end
```

above is to show the special meaning of ESC - hard to show, hard to enter. In the edit window here on stackexchange I get a small kind of icon as [ESC].

With `cat -A colorhello > col.txt` instead:

```
^[[36m $
hello36$
^[[35m $
hello35$
^[[37m $
hello end$
$
$
```

(two empty lines at the end, obviously)
(the col.txt I open in another firefox tab to copy)

Inside vim the escape shows darkblue as "^[". To insert one: ctrl-v [ESC].

In vi, ESC is just `^[` and when I try to put the cursor on the "^", my screen flickers once.

Of course, this is a kind of rudimentary "rich text" format, as pointed out in an answer. These ESCapes and control sequences just are there, and probably are more annoying than gray text.

(I noticed the ANSI control sequences for changing the cursor (ESC [?1;2;3c) in my `vimrc` file take effect when I `cat` that file - prompt and cursor get colorized)

Of course you have to `cat` to see the colors - they are interpreted by the terminal. In an editor they have no meaning. And I don't think syntax highlighting for control sequences would be...well invested time.

---

ADDED: shouldn't you turn it the other way round: insert some short magic string instead of the ESC sequence so that you can easily highlight it linewise. A bit like dmesg looks with the bracketed timestamp

```
[info] Yor first logline...in normal color
[info] Another normal line
[warn] This could appear yellow in your editor
[error] This sticks out red and sticks also out b/w
[info] And so on
```

Like that you CAN see colors if you want, plus what they mean *("Oh I thought this message was unimportant because it was in such a brilliant red hue" :-)* and it is still looks nice when you just cat it.

(Syntax highlighting in vim is great once you turn off all those over-the-top syntax files!)